# ASP.net - My username writes out more then one time?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

The problem when i click on my `GridView` as i want to watch more members on the other pages this one apears after reloading: http://i.gyazo.com/48e040f1d276984c0d3c6bfd8c38c974.png

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label_welcome" runat="server" Text="Välkommen mr:"></asp:Label>

</div>
    <asp:Button ID="B_logout" runat="server" OnClick="B_logout_Click" Text="Logga ut" />
    <br />
    <br />
<embed src="CV.pdf" width=1400px height=1000px >
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRegister" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegisterConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRegister" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="195px" Width="254px" DataKeyNames="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Användarnamn" HeaderText="Användarnamn" SortExpression="Användarnamn" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lösenord" HeaderText="Lösenord" SortExpression="Lösenord" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Land" HeaderText="Land" SortExpression="Land" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fullnamn" HeaderText="Fullnamn" SortExpression="Fullnamn" />
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>

    <br />
    </form>

</div>
```

Above is my code with the buttons 'n' stuff

```
   public partial class _1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
            {
                Label_welcome.Text += Session["New"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged");
        }
        protected void B_logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["New"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code which actually fills in the text for `Label_welcome`. I suspect you are doing something like `Label_welcome.Text += username;` which causes the double display, but we can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Yes sorry i updated the code above!

Comment: I'd also hazard a good bet that the session data is not being preserved correctly, or is timing out and being expunged on a very short interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `Text` property for a `Label`, the value you have put in is stored in the `ViewState` for the page and reconstructed when you do a postback. It is *not* read fresh from the aspx source code every time.  So the value of your `Text` property in your code is doing this:

1. First Request:

   - Read `ViewState`: (nothing there)
   - Read aspx page: **"Välkommen mr:"**
   - Page_Load: `Text += "admin"` = `"Välkommen mr:" + "admin"` = **"Välkommen mr:admin"**
   - Request finishes - Value is stored in `ViewState`
2. Second Request:

   - Read from `ViewState`: **"Välkommen mr:admin"**
   - Read from aspx page - skipped because found in `ViewState`
   - Page_Load: `Text += "admin"` = `"Välkommen mr:admin" + "admin"` = **"Välkommen mr:adminadmin"**
   - Request finishes - Value is stored in `ViewState`

To get around this you have two options:

1. Disable `ViewState` for the `Label` using [`EnableViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate(v=vs.110).aspx). This means the text won't be saved, but note that other properties you set on it won't either:

`<asp:Label ID="Label_welcome" runat="server" Text="Välkommen mr:" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>`

2. Set the full Text instead of using +=:

`Label_welcome.Text = "Välkommen mr:" + Session["New"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code I can see that your trying to keep a simple single session variable to mange the logged in state of your web page.

The biggest problem with doing things this way is that the ASP.NET session cache is very, very fragile.

Without being able to see the application config, I would make an educated guess that the default of 20 minutes is in effect here.

That means if the page sits still with nothing being clicked on or interacted with for 20 minutes or more then you'll find all of a sudden that any state you did save is now gone.

If your creating .NET web applications on a remote host, you might even find that your hosting provider has decreased that even further (I've seen them as low as 5 to 10 minutes before.

If you want to implement a robust and correctly functioning Login/Logout scenario, then please use the the tools that .NET actually provides for you in the form of the ASP.NET Membership system.

The "4 Guys from Rolla" website has a great multi part series on using it, which can be found here : https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

I would also recommend looking at the newer "ASP.NET Identity services" stuff, especially with everything moving toward Owin & Katana self hosting stacks.

ASP.NET Identity is the new identity login services for the upcoming "One Platform" Microsoft vision where everything is modular and interchangeable and where one single identity system can provide logging in services from everything on a local machine right through to using an OAuth provider such as Google or Twitter to authenticate with.